# How to filter a django OR query correctly

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-q

I tried to make an OR query with django q. But the number of results is differnt to filter in single queries:

```
//result is 7
len(Project.objects.filter(Q(moderator='A') | Q(participant='B')))

//result is 6
len(Project.objects.filter(Q(moderator='A')))

//result is 0
len(Project.objects.filter(Q(participant='B')))
```

since the third query responses a empty queryset, I expect the same results with first and second query. What is here the problem?

I got the same result if I do:

```
//len is 6
q1 = Project.objects.filter(Q(moderator='A'))

//len is 0
q2 = Project.objects.filter(Q(participant='B'))

//len is 7
q1 | q2
```

I can resolve this with distinct(). But how can a merge with a querset of 0 produce more results than before?

Comment: Are `moderator` and `participant` many-to-many fields?

Comment: Can you post your Project model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if both `moderator` and `participant` are `ManyToManyField`s, in that case, it will make two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s, and the `Project` object will thus be repeated for each record that matches.

We can work with [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to prevent returning the same `Project` multiple times:

```
len(Project.objects.filter(
    Q(moderator='A') | Q(participant='B')
).distinct())
```

You can also work with [**`.count()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) to count at the database side, which is more efficient than counting at the Django/Python layer:

```
Project.objects.filter(
    Q(moderator='A') | Q(participant='B')
).distinct().count()
```

Comment: It is correct, both are ManyToMany fields. But I still get why this happens. I need to think about. Thanks so far.

Comment: @Gunter: because it makes a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, this means that if there is no participant equal to `B`, it will still create a line where the `B` object is `NULL`, so we are counting one extra, even if there is no match.